# c++ test whether double is #INF

Tags: c++, double, nan

I would like to isolate the behavior when some `double` value is a `NaN` or an `#INF`. To detect a `NaN`, I test

```
doubleVal != doubleVal
```

What about an `#INF`? Will this test be true when the `doubleVal` is an `#INF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about multiplication by `1.` once you're sure it's not `NaN`?

http://ideone.com/97FNu

You could also use [`isinf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isinf.html) and [`isnan`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isnan.html), but those might incur some overhead depending on their implementation.

A third alternative is using the C max value macros (or equivalent `std::numeric_limits`):

```
 bool is_inf_or_nan(double x) 
{
    return !(x <= DBL_MAX && x >= -DBL_MAX); 
}
```

Comment: I like this alternative solution

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using c++11, then you'll need `<boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp>` instead of `<cmath>`, with corresponding namespace change.

```
#include <cmath> // or <boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp>
// ...

    if(isinf(num)){
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Also, you should probably use `std::isnan` to check for NaN, if only because it's more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [header-only library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html) present in Boost that have neat tools to deal with floating point datatypes

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp>
```

You get the following functions:

```
template <class T> bool isfinite(T z);
template <class T> bool isinf(T t);
template <class T> bool isnan(T t);
template <class T> bool isnormal(T t);
```